# Not getting output from serial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a simple script that is a serial connection to a device.
I am trying to send a command but somehow i am not getting the output but rather my input.
Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200, timeout=1)
x = ser.write('AT')          #  write a string
s = ser.read(x)        # read x bytes (timeout)
#line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
print (s)
ser.close()
```

NB: All i need is use "write" to send a command and "read" to get the output.

Never mind!!!
I managed to fix my problem by trying to simulate the enter key, printing response in a new line and printing more than one byte(NB:Not specifying the byte amount produced "A" as a generic response for all successful outputs and "C" for all failed outputs.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200, timeout=1)
x = ser.write('AT' + '\r\n')          #  write a string
s = ser.read(100)        # read x bytes (timeout)
#line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
print (s)
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working answer is included in the edit above. I will also consider any better solution. Thanks for looking.